# Was bedeutet der Ausdruck "jeweils extra nach"?

Tags: phrase

Ich habe gerade eine E-Mail erhalten, in der folgendes steht:

> Für uns zählt das Datum, welches uns die Verwaltung bestätigt. **Wir haben jeweils extra nach um diese Bestätigung zu erhalten**.

Was bedeutet denn eigentlich das fett markierte genau?

Comment: Der Satz ist kompletter Nonsens. Stelle sicher, dass dies kein Spam / Phishing ist.

Comment: The sentence is incomplete. I would guess that the author wanted to write *nachgefragt,* (or *nachgehakt,*) instead of *nach*.

Comment: I'ts a simple typo. "Wir ha**k**en jeweils extra nach, um..."

Comment: Although b and k aren’t next to each other, so there’s a confounding layer of a spellchecker or changing one’s mind mid-sentence involved.

Comment: Depending on what device the E-Mail was written on, it is also possible that an autocorrection did mess up the sentence. Some people don't re-read what they have written before pressing "send" :-( . Both the suggestions of RHa and tohuwawohu are possible explanations for what the writer intended to write.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ist kein Betrug; es geht um eine ausstehende Schlussrechnung :)

Comment: @Crazydre besser: du hast EINE E-Mail bekommen oder EINE Mail, in DER steht ... Email ist überwiegend weiblich, auch wenn es in Wörterbüchern noch als Femininum und Neutrum steht.

Comment: @Dan Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a summary of comments by [RAh](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/26847/rha) and [tohuwawohu](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/392/tohuwawohu), since comments might be deleted some time:

This sentence is incomplete, at least one word or word-part is missing.
Possible versions of what the sentence should have been:

> Wir ha**k**en jeweils extra nach, um diese Bestätigung zu erhalten.
>   Wir haben jeweils extra nach**gefragt**, um diese Bestätigung zu erhalten.
>   Wir haben jeweils extra nach**gehakt**, um diese Bestätigung zu erhalten.

The second and third versions could result in the wrong sentence when the author was inattentive while re-arranging sentence parts (or sloppy copy-paste actions), the first could either be a typo from the author or a mistake made by the autocorrection.